# How to add Handler on Cell in Google Visualization Table in GWT?

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

Google Visualization API for GWT provides control over rows only.
How to get control over a particular cell in Visualization Table? 
selection.isCell() doesn't give true result in any case.

```
private SelectHandler createSelectHandler(final PieChart chart) {
return new SelectHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    String message = "";

    // May be multiple selections.
    JsArray<Selection> selections = chart.getSelections();

    for (int i = 0; i < selections.length(); i++) {
      // add a new line for each selection
      message += i == 0 ? "" : "\n";

      Selection selection = selections.get(i);

      if (selection.isCell()) {
        // isCell() returns true if a cell has been selected.

        // getRow() returns the row number of the selected cell.
        int row = selection.getRow();
        // getColumn() returns the column number of the selected cell.
        int column = selection.getColumn();
        message += "cell " + row + ":" + column + " selected";
      } else if (selection.isRow()) {
        // isRow() returns true if an entire row has been selected.

        // getRow() returns the row number of the selected row.
        int row = selection.getRow();
        message += "row " + row + " selected";
      } else {
        // unreachable
        message += "Pie chart selections should be either row selections or cell selections.";
        message += "  Other visualizations support column selections as well.";
      }
    }

    Window.alert(message);
  }
};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Google Table has 4 events: ready,select,page,sort.

When you sort or paginate, it stops listening the ready event. 
To have the cell click working after pagination or sort you need to add the click listener on all of them.

You can use click instead of mouseover.
On select event I use getSelection to be able to get and set the selected row properties.

```
var colIndex;

google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    $("#table").find("td").each(function() {    
        $(this).mouseover(function(){
            colIndex=$(this).index();
        });
    }); 
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort', function () {
    $("#table").find("td").each(function() {    
        $(this).mouseover(function(){
            colIndex=$(this).index();
        });
    });
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'page', function (event) {
    $("#tableGoogle").find("td").each(function() {    
        $(this).mouseover(function(){
            colIndex=$(this).index();
        });
    });
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function () {
    var selection = table.getSelection();
    var item;
    if(selection.length!=0){
        lastSelection=selection;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < lastSelection.length; i++) {
        item = lastSelection[i];
    }

    switch (colIndex){
        case 0: 
           data.setValue(item.row,index,true);
           // YOUR CODE FOR COLUMN 0
        break;      
        case 1:
            var id=data.getRowProperty(item.row, 'id');
           // YOUR CODE FOR COLUMN 1
        break;
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Table Visualization does not pass column information in the selection event, so you cannot identify an individual cell this way.  You will need to register a click event handler on the cells of the table and then determine the cell's row and column indices.  Here's one way to do it using jQuery:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    $('#table_div td').click(function () {
        var column = $(this).index();
        var row = $(this).parent().index() - 1; // subtract 1 for the table header
        console.log(row, column);
    });
});
```

You'll have to adapt the event handler to the method used in the GWT Viz API package, but the jQuery code should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowIndex;
var colIndex;
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
jQuery("#table").on("click", "td:not(.google-visualization-table-th)", function() {
   colIndex = jQuery(this).index();
   rowIndex = jQuery(this).parent().index() - 1;
   alert("row "+rowIndex+" col "+colIndex);
   //put rest of function here
});
```

This gets rowindex based on the row of the html. To get the rowindex based on the data (where the row's index won't change even if you sort the table and it's position changes) use

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function() {               
    var selected=table.getChart().getSelection();
    var item=selected[0];
    rowIndex=item.row;
});
```

This will run before the code in the .on("click", ...) function in the ready function.